# Reversing a byte string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, endianness

I find out the following code in python:

```
def ExtractShellcodeArm(_arg_name):
    ObjDumpOutput(_arg_name)
    print("\033[101m\033[1mExtracted Shellcode:\033[0m\n")

    proc = subprocess.Popen(['objdump','-d',_arg_name], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    while True:
        line = proc.stdout.readline()
        if line != b'':
            array = line.decode().rstrip().split(':')
            if len(array) > 1:
                if array[1]:
                    array2 =  array[1].split(' ')
                    array2 = array2[0].lstrip().rstrip()
                    if array2:
                        sc_part = '\t"'
                        sc_part += '\\x'
                        sc_part += '\\x'.join(a+b for a,b in zip(array2[::2], array2[1::2]))
                        sc_part += '"+'
                        print(sc_part)
        else:
           break
```

After I run this code in python3 it gives me the result of the objdump tools like the following:

```
"\xe2\x8f\x60\x01"+
"\xe1\x2f\xff\x16"+
"\x22\x0c"+
"\x46\x79"+
"\x31\x0e"+
"\x20\x01"+
"\x27\x04"+
"\xdf\x01"+
"\x1b\x24"+
"\x1c\x20"+
"\x27\x01"+
"\xdf\x01"+
"\x6c\x6c\x65\x48"+
"\x6f\x57\x20\x6f"+
"\x0a\x64\x6c\x72"+
```

But I want it shows the result in the big endian format. How can I change this represantion in python function. for example I want this code shows the result like the following:

```
"\x01\x60\x8f\xe2"+
"\x16\xff\x2f\xe1"+
"\x0c\x22"+
"\x79\x46"+
...
```

Comment: Try: `print(sc_part[::-1])`

Comment: This command reversed whole the string. But I want the string reveresed 2 byte 2byte.

Comment: I want string "\xe2\x8f\x60\x01" becomes "\x01\x60\x8f\xe2".

Comment: you might need `struct` module. Wait i'll post an answer

Answer (score 0):

It's not the prettiest code, but this works:

```
''.join(a+b for a, b in zip(s[::-2], s[-2::-2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store each complete opcode (set of bytes) as an element in a list when you parse them, and then iterate over the list, flipping the bytes in the opcode one at a time. For example, rather than `opcodes "\xcd\x80" + "\xeb\xfe"` use `opcodes = ["\xcd\x80", "\xeb\xfe"`. You should have no problem iterating over the list and reversing each opcode.

Another option is using shell utilities to reverse the bytes before they are received by Python by piping the objdump command to tools like sed and awk to do this by splitting up the bytes on each line into columns and then printing the columns backwards.